# How can I compute descriptive statistics within variable levels for which I have already generated counts?

Tags: r

I am trying to obtain detailed descriptive statistics. I have selected three variables (Baseline, Experience, and Engagement_overall) from the main data frame Users and have calculated sample sizes for each. Here is one example using this code:

```
Engagement <- 
    Users %>%
    group_by(Engagement_overall)%>%
    summarise(engagement_count=n())
```

[Here is the output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaiOV.png)

I am trying to calculate the average age, %of females, %of the province (Ontario, British-Columbia, and Newfoundland-Labrador), median personal income, and baseline mean steps per day within each level of Engagement_overall (including the other variables of Baseline and Experience). All aforementioned variables with the exception of baseline mean steps per day are included in the main data frame Users:

[Main data frame Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPXlc.png)

How could I write a code to include the metrics (average age, %of females, %of the province, median personal income, and baseline mean steps per day) within each level of Engagement_overall? Baseline and Experience also have 4 levels. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: If you still have the columns age, gender, ect.. in your `Users` data frame, you should be able to keep adding columns to the `summarise` command separated by a comma.  Example: `summarise(engagement_count=n(), avg_age=mean(age), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make the tables separately then join all of them.  For an example, I randomly generated some data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  user_id = 1:100,
  gender = sample(c('Male', 'Female'), 100, replace = T),
  age = sample(10:80, 100, replace = T),
  income_level = sample(c('10k-20k', '20k-50k', '50k-70k', '70k+'), 100, replace = T),
  province = sample(c('ON', 'BC', 'NL'), 100, replace = T),
  baseline = sample(c('low', 'medium', 'high'), 100, replace = T),
  experience = sample(1:3, 100, replace = T),
  engagement_overall = sample(1:3, 100, replace = T)
)
```

We can find the percentage of females by finding the average of a binary variable.

```
fm <- df %>% 
  mutate(female = if_else(gender == 'Female', 1, 0)) %>% # make a column that has value 1 if female, otherwise value is 0
  group_by(engagement_overall, province) %>% # 
  summarise(perc_female = mean(female))
```

Make the province table in the same way

```
prv <- df %>% 
  group_by(engagement_overall, province) %>% 
  summarise(prov_count = n()) %>% 
  group_by(engagement_overall) %>% 
  mutate(total = sum(prov_count),
         prov_count_freq = prov_count/total) %>% 
  select(engagement_overall, province, prov_count_freq)
```

Then you can combind them all using `inner_join`

```
summary_df <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(engagement_overall, province) %>% 
  summarise(avg_age = mean(age)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  inner_join(fm) %>% 
  inner_join(prv)
```

As for baseline and median income, you can't do statistics on qualitative data, but you could find the mode, which you can do in a similar way.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(engagement_overall, province, baseline) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  filter(count == max(count))
```

If you wanted to find median age, you could make the column numeric by replacing each category with a number.  For example replace '20-40k' with 30.  Maybe checkout the `case_when` function from dplyr to do this.

```
?case_when
```

Comment: Thank you very much. There are a few errors I was hoping you could help me out with.I will elaborate in the answer below given the character count limit

Comment: Users <- tibble(
  x = 1:584760,
  gender = sample(c('Male', 'Female'), 584760, replace = T),
  age = sample(0:120, 584760, replace = T),
  income_level = sample(c('<20k', '20-40k', '40-60k', '60-80k', '80-100k', '100-150k', '150k+', 'Didn't Complete Survey', 'Don't Know', 'Rather Not Say', 'NA' ), 584760, replace = T),
  province = sample(c('ON', 'BC', 'NL'), 584760, replace = T),
  baseline = sample(c('low', 'medium', 'high', 'NA'), 584760, replace = T),
  experience = sample(1:3,'NA', 584760, replace = T),
  engagement_overall = sample(1:3,'NA', 584760, replace = T)

Comment: Is accompanied by:

Comment: income_level = sample(c('<20k', '20-40k', '40-60k', '60-80k', '80-100k', '100-150k', '150k+', 'Didn't Complete Survey', 'Don't Know', 'Rather Not Say', 'NA' ), 584760, replace = T),
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  age = sample(0:120, 584760, replace = T),
  income_level = sample(c('<20k', '20-40k', '40-60k', '60-80k', '80-100k', '100-150k', '150k+', 'Didn't"

Comment: province = sample(c('ON', 'BC', 'NL'), 584760, replace = T),
Error: unexpected ',' in "  province = sample(c('ON', 'BC', 'NL'), 584760, replace = T),"
>   baseline = sample(c('low', 'medium', 'high', 'NA'), 584760, replace = T),
Error: unexpected ',' in "  baseline = sample(c('low', 'medium', 'high', 'NA'), 584760, replace = T),"

Comment: experience = sample(1:3,'NA', 584760, replace = T),
Error: unexpected ',' in "  experience = sample(1:3,'NA', 584760, replace = T),"
>   engagement_overall = sample(1:3,'NA', 584760, replace = T)
Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : 
  invalid 'size' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : NAs introduced by coercion
> )

Comment: When you create the random data, you need to pass a vector as the first argument in `sample`.  So `1:3,'NA'` is not a vector, instead pass `c(1:3, NA)`.  Also you don't need quotes when writing NA.  Another reason there is an error is because you are specifying a string with single quotes, and use the same character as an apostrophe when you write `'Don't Know'`.  Instead you can use double quotes.  This way you can still use a single quote as an apostrophe.  For example: `"Don't Know"`.  Here is some random sample data that will work

Comment: ```Users <- 
  tibble(
    gender = sample(c('M'ale, 'Female'), 584760, replace = T), 
    age = sample(0:120, 584760, replace = T), 
    income_level = sample(c('<20k', '20-40k', '40-60k', '60-80k', '80-100k', '100-150k', '150k+', "Didn't Complete Survey", "Don't Know", 'Rather Not Say', NA ), 584760, replace = T), 
    province = sample(c('ON', 'BC', 'NL'), 584760, replace = T),
    baseline = sample(c('low', 'medium', 'high', NA), 584760, replace = T), 
    experience = sample(c(1:3,NA), 584760, replace = T), 
    engagement_overall = sample(c(1:3,NA), 584760, replace = T))```